# angular2 ngFor not display data

Tags: angular

This is my code

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-jobcompleted',
  templateUrl: './jobcompleted.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./jobcompleted.component.scss']
})

export class JobcompletedComponent {

  name: string;
  email: string
  address: string;
  hobbies: string[];
  showHobbies: boolean;

  constructor(){
  this.name = "john doe",
  this.email = "john@gmail.com",
  this.address = "ukay perdana"
  this.hobbies= ['music','movies','sport'];
  this.showHobbies = true;
  }
  tooggleHobbies(){}
}
```

my template

```
<h2>Hello {{ name }}</h2>
<h2>email : {{ email }}</h2>
<h2>address : {{ address }}</h2>
<h2>hobby</h2>
<ul>
  <li ngFor="let hobby of hobbies">{{ hobby }}</li>
</ul>
```

But the `ngFor` does not display any data:

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E4qT2.jpg)

I've tried many style of code but none of them works for me:-

```
    <ul>
      <li *ngFor="let hobby of hobbies">{{ hobby }}</li>
    </ul>

<ul>
      <li *ngFor="#hobby of hobbies">{{ hobby }}</li>
    </ul>

<ul>
          <li ngFor="#hobby of hobbies">{{ hobby }}</li>
        </ul>
```

What is wrong with my code? And this is my angular version

```
@angular/cli: 1.0.0-beta.31
node: 6.9.2
os: win32 x64
@angular/common: 2.4.7
@angular/compiler: 2.4.7
@angular/core: 2.4.7
@angular/forms: 2.4.7
@angular/http: 2.4.7
@angular/platform-browser: 2.4.7
@angular/platform-browser-dynamic: 2.4.7
@angular/router: 3.4.7
@angular/cli: 1.0.0-beta.31
@angular/compiler-cli: 2.4.7
```

Comment: I just tried `<li *ngFor="let hobby of hobbies">{{ hobby }}</li>` and it worked... Make sure you're recompiling your TypeScript and reloading your server... If that fails, check your console for errors.

Comment: Any errors?  pic shows one dot so an `li` is being displayed right?  What do elements look like in dev tools?  Above the list add `<pre>{{ hobbies | json }}</pre>` to make sure the context has the data you expect

Comment: <ul>
  <li *ngFor="let hobby of hobbies">{{ hobby }}</li>
</ul>

Comment: i don't have any errors on my console..

Comment: @uetoaya Please recreate the issue in a plunker :)

Answer (score 1):

Please check the image , It works for me.

[image]

Comment: Avoid link only answers.

Comment: wow... i just notice that at the bottom of my code does not have @NgModule.. but when i put NgModule i got an error said "Cannot find name 'NgModule'.)"

Comment: import ngModule see top imports

Answer (score 0):

It's

```
<h2>Hello {{ name }}</h2>
<h2>email : {{ email }}</h2>
<h2>address : {{ address }}</h2>
<h2>hobby</h2>
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let hobby of hobbies">{{ hobby }}</li>
</ul>
```

`*ngFor`, `*ngIf`, `*ngSwitchCase`, structural directives needs an `*` before the directive.

Comment: <ul>
  <li [ERROR ->]*ngFor="let hobby of hobbies">{{ hobby }}</li>
</ul>

Answer (score 0):

You can put *ngFor on ul.

```
 <ul *ngFor="let hobby of hobbies">
  <li>{{hobby}}</li>
</ul>
```

Plunker : https://plnkr.co/edit/9i0lwxaJSmnCVcZVCen1?p=preview

Comment: <ul>
  <li [ERROR ->]*ngFor="let hobby of hobbies">{{ hobby }}</li>
</ul>